# Cannot instantiate the type Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java. I want to read input through scanner.
I am getting error as cannot 'instantiate the type scanner'.

```
import java.util.*;  
import java.io.File;  

public class Factors {  

//string declaration  
static String filename;  

public static void main(String args[]){  
    //scanner initialization, needs to be done in every program that reads from user  
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
    int caseIndex=0;  

    //prompts user for filename  
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file you would like to read from.");  
    filename = input.nextString();  

    //checks if filename exists  
    if(input.exists())  
        System.out.println(inp.getName() + "exists!");  
    else  
        System.out.println("File name does not exist!");  



 }  

}
```

I am not understanding where i am lacking.
Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the relevant code. Otherwise we can only guess what is wrong.

Comment: There is more than one `Scanner` type. Are you sure you are using `java.util.Scanner`?

Comment: Java is case sensitive. Make sure you have new Scanner(...) instead of new scanner(...)

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringVariables {

Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
}

Comment: Added with code but not getting output

Comment: Can not reproduce... but I am getting a bunch of other errors. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: `Scanner` does not have methods `nextString()` or `exists()`.  The variable `inp` does not exist.  This code does not compile!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scanner` does not have methods `nextString()` and `exists()` methods. I think your requirement is to check that file is present or not. Do it like this:

```
    import java.util.*;  
    import java.io.File;  

    public class Factors 
    { 
        static String filename;  
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
            //scanner initialization, needs to be done in every program that reads from user  
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
            int caseIndex=0;  

            //prompts user for filename  
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file you would like to read from.");  
            filename = input.nextLine();  
            File file=new File(filename);
            //checks if filename exists  
            if(file.exists())  
                System.out.println(file.getName() + "exists!");  
            else  
                System.out.println("File name does not exist!");  
    }

}
```